# Aspect Ratio of Cylinder, Pyramid and Dome

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

The aspect ratio can easily be defined for rectangular geometries ($AR = height/width$). Is there a definition for aspect ratio of a dome, cylinder, and pyramid (Here standard pyramid and dome were meant; like a square right pyramid and a semi-circular dome)?

Comment: There are many types of domes, cylinders and pyramids. Which ones are you talking about?

Comment: I don't know many types of domes or pyramids. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I don't have a reference, but domes are basically a section of a round solid object, so there are all kinds of those. A pyramid is a solid which can have any kind of polygon as a base, so those are also abundant. If you're talking about the standard objects, like a square right pyramid and a semi-circular dome, you should mention that.